# ImportError cannot import name SparkContext

Tags: python, unix, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm setting the below exports from the shell.

```
export SPARK_HOME="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/lib/spark"
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH 
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
```

Confirmed SPARK_HOME folder contents:

```
ls /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/lib/spark -l

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 assembly
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 cloudera
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    15 Dec  1 19:56 conf -> /etc/spark/conf
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 examples
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:52 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46083 Aug 12 14:47 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22559 Aug 12 14:47 NOTICE
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 python
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Aug 12 14:47 RELEASE
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Aug 12 14:47 ui-resources
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    19 Dec  1 19:56 work -> /var/run/spark/work
```

Running the below code as **spark-submit TestPyEnv.py**

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
#os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
#sys.path.append("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/lib/spark/python/")

help('modules')
try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark import SparkConf

    print ("Successfully imported Spark Modules")

except ImportError as e:
    print ("Can not import Spark Modules", e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Getting the below output:

```
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/numerix/__init__.py:18: DeprecationWarning:
**********************************************************
matplotlib.numerix and all its subpackages are deprecated.
They will be removed soon.  Please use numpy instead.
**********************************************************

  warnings.warn(msg, DeprecationWarning)

** (TestPyEnv.py:13441): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowState' as flags when in fact it is of type 'GEnum'

** (TestPyEnv.py:13441): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowActions' as flags when in fact it is of type 'GEnum'

** (TestPyEnv.py:13441): WARNING **: Trying to register gtype 'WnckWindowMoveResizeMask' as flags when in fact it is of type 'GEnum'
2015-12-11 17:58:50.887115: ERROR: Could not load the stocks from /home/irmprot/.gnome2/invest-applet/stocks.pickle: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/irmprot/.gnome2/invest-applet/stocks.pickle'
BaseHTTPServer      calendar            ipalib              repr
Bastion             cas                 ipapython           resource
CDROM               cgi                 itertools           rexec
CGIHTTPServer       cgitb               iwlib               rfc822
CORBA               chunk               ixf86config         rhn
ConfigParser        cmath               json                rhsm
Cookie              cmd                 kerberos            rlcompleter
Crypto              code                keyword             robotparser
DLFCN               codecs              krbV                rpm
DocXMLRPCServer     codeop              ldap                rpmUtils
HTMLParser          collections         ldapurl             runpy
IN                  colorsys            ldif                scdate
IRM_RAW_inputPreprocessor commands            lib2to3             sched
LoadBaseAndIntegrated compileall          libproxy            select
M2Crypto            compiler            libsvn              selinux
MimeWriter          contextlib          libuser             sets
ORBit               cookielib           libxml2             setuptools
OpenSSL             copy                libxml2mod          sgmllib
PortableServer      copy_reg            linecache           sha
Pyspark-Step1-Dec9  cracklib            linuxaudiodev       shelve
Pyspark-Step1-latest crypt               locale              shlex
Queue               csv                 logging             shutil
SSSDConfig          ctypes              lxml                signal
SimpleHTTPServer    curl                macpath             simplejson
SimpleXMLRPCServer  curses              macurl2path         site
SocketServer        datetime            mailbox             slip
StringIO            dateutil            mailcap             smtpd
TYPES               dbhash              markupbase          smtplib
TestPyEnv           dbm                 marshal             snack
UserDict            dbus                math                sndhdr
UserList            dbus_bindings       matplotlib          socket
UserString          decimal             md5                 sos
_LWPCookieJar       default_encoding_utf8 meh                 spwd
_MozillaCookieJar   difflib             mhlib               sqlite3
__builtin__         dircache            mimetools           sqlitecachec
__future__          dis                 mimetypes           sre
_abcoll             distutils           mimify              sre_compile
_ast                dl                  mmap                sre_constants
_bisect             dmidecode           modulefinder        sre_parse
_bsddb              dmidecodemod        mpl_toolkits        ssl
_bytesio            doctest             multifile           stat
_codecs             drv_libxml2         multiprocessing     statvfs
_codecs_cn          dsextras            mutex               string
_codecs_hk          dsml                netaddr             stringold
_codecs_iso2022     dumbdbm             netrc               stringprep
_codecs_jp          dummy_thread        new                 strop
_codecs_kr          dummy_threading     nis                 struct
_codecs_tw          easy_install        nntplib             subprocess
_collections        egg                 nose                sunau
_cracklib           email               nss                 sunaudio
_crypt              encodings           ntpath              svn
_csv                errno               nturl2path          symbol
_ctypes             ethtool             numbers             symtable
_curses             exceptions          numpy               sys
_curses_panel       fcntl               opcode              syslog
_dbus_bindings      filecmp             operator            system_config_keyboard
_dbus_glib_bindings fileinput           optparse            tabnanny
_elementtree        firstboot           orca                talloc
_fileio             fnmatch             os                  tarfile
_functools          formatter           os2emxpath          telnetlib
_hashlib            fpformat            ossaudiodev         tempfile
_heapq              fractions           packagekit          termios
_hotshot            ftplib              pango               test
_json               functools           pangocairo          tests
_ldap               future_builtins     paramiko            textwrap
_locale             gc                  parser              this
_lsprof             gconf               pdb                 thread
_multibytecodec     gdbm                pickle              threading
_multiprocessing    genericpath         pickletools         time
_random             getopt              pipes               timeit
_snack              getpass             pkg_resources       timing
_socket             gettext             pkgutil             toaiff
_sqlite3            gio                 platform            token
_sqlitecache        glib                plistlib            tokenize
_sre                glob                popen2              trace
_ssl                gmenu               poplib              traceback
_strptime           gnome               posix               tty
_struct             gnomeapplet         posixfile           types
_symtable           gnomecanvas         posixpath           unicodedata
_threading_local    gnomevfs            pprint              unittest
_warnings           gobject             profile             urlgrabber
_weakref            gpgme               pstats              urllib
abc                 grp                 pty                 urllib2
abrt_exception_handler gtk                 pwd                 urlparse
acutil              gtkunixprint        py4j                user
aifc                gudev               py_compile          uu
anydbm              gzip                pyatspi             uuid
array               hashlib             pyclbr              vte
ast                 heapq               pycurl              warnings
asynchat            hmac                pydoc               wave
asyncore            hotshot             pydoc_topics        weakref
atexit              htmlentitydefs      pyexpat             webbrowser
atk                 htmllib             pygtk               whichdb
audiodev            httplib             pyhbac              wnck
audioop             idlelib             pylab               wsgiref
base64              ihooks              pyspark             xdrlib
bdb                 imageop             pysss               xf86config
binascii            imaplib             pysss_murmur        xml
binhex              imghdr              pytz                xmllib
bisect              imp                 quopri              xmlrpclib
bonobo              imputil             random              xxsubtype
bsddb               iniparse            re                  yum
bz2                 inspect             readline            yumutils
cPickle             invest              redhat_support_lib  zipfile
cProfile            io                  redhat_support_tool zipimport
cStringIO           iotop               report              zlib
cairo               ipaclient           reportclient

Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose descriptions contain the word "spam".

('Can not import Spark Modules', ImportError('cannot import name SparkContext',))
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

I'm not able to figure out for the life of my why the SparkContext is not working.

**('Can not import Spark Modules', ImportError('cannot import name SparkContext',))**

Comment: Are you able to launch the `pyspark` interactive shell through the terminal?

Comment: yes, the pyspark shell absolutely works. Infact, i figured out the PYTHONPATH and SPARKHOME env variables by printing them from the pyspark shell.

Comment: Were you able to import the `SparkContext` via the interactive shell?

Comment: yes, everything works fine through the pySpark shell

Comment: I suppose it may have something to do with the `PYTHONPATH`. Although I'm not completely sure. Could you share the value in `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I also had the same issue even though I had pasted pyspark and py4j to site-packages. But this time I tried copy pasting pyspark.egg-info also to my C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages. Now it works!